# PHP / Extension API mismatch

Tags: php, windows, apache-http-server

I recently upgraded to Apache 2.4.7 (x86) and PHP 5.5.9 (x86 as Apache module) on Windows 7 x64.  I downloaded the Apache binary from [apachelounge.com](http://apachelounge.com) and the PHP binary from [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net).

Now the error logs keep telling me that the PHP build API and certain extension APIs (php_fileinfo.dll for instance) are mismatched.  I downgraded back to Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.6, using the original MSI's I previously installed them with, and I have the same problem!

Does anyone know what has caused this?

Comment: Have you installed the 64bit version of Java? If so, that can be one of the reasons.

Comment: Is the 64bit version of Java a good thing or a bad thing!?

Comment: Some 32bit software cannot deal with 64bit version of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  I'm not sure what could have created the problem but I'm sure it had something to do with the 'extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"' line in php.ini.

I moved dll files around and found that they worked when they were in C:\PHP.  Then I renamed the extensions folder to C:\PHP\extensions and modified php.ini to reflect it and everything worked!  Then I changed it back and it was running perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that you either did not properly uninstall the previous versions.

OR

You have at some stage copied something from either Apache or PHP into somewhere like C:\windows\system32 or something like that and whatever that was was not removed when you uninstalled the previous versions, and it is that that is causing the problems.

OR

You have something added to your PATH and did not chnage it.

It should not be necessary to copy anything to the Windows folder or have anything hardcoded onto your PATH.

Comment: Thanks, RiggsFolly!  How would I know if there are leftovers in System32?  And, come to think of it, I vaguely recall editing my PATH at some stage...

At any rate, I think my whole PC is due for a format, and a re-install of 32bit Windows this time.

Comment: So, I completely reinstalled Windows 7, 32bit this time, with latest updates, including Update 4 for Visual Studio 2012.  Then I extracted Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5 and I still get a mismatch!  This time it's telling me that the versions match but the modules are NTS!

Comment: If you download a Thread Safe APache then you have to use a Thread Safe PHP as well, and all the module for PHP must also be Thread Safe.

Comment: Yip, Thread Safe Apache installed!  And I'm using the modules that came with PHP (fileinfo, mysql, mysqli).

Comment: Teh PHP has to be compiled Thread Safe also!!

Comment: I didn't compile PHP!  I used the zip file from windows.php.net!  And it's not an Apache error anyway, I'm getting the same on IIS.

Comment: Have you considered scrapping the lot and installing something like WAMPServer or XAMPP. Both of these do thsi job with little or no pain at all and are a great option for those that find DIY a problem.

Comment: XAMPP had the same problem!  It's obviously something to do with my system setup, maybe some application or preference that I always use.  Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this means anything but when I open the extensions (fileinfo.dll, mysql.dll, mysqli.dll) in Dependency Walker, I get a missing dll alert; php5ts.dll.  I know that's a thread-safety-related module but I understood that PHP 5.5 didn't use it anymore.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well it still exists in my 5.5.3 and 5.5.8 installation folders.

Comment: If you used an .msi install try searching your registry for anything to do with PHP, maybe but not exclusively for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>PHP as some people suggest this is required but my system runs without any registry changes quite happily

Comment: Nah, I didn't use the MSI - I extracted from the zip file.  And searching the registry didn't return anything.  :(  Also, yip; php5ts.dll is also in my PHP root folder.  I wonder why the extensions cant find it?